# when trying to run mysql shell 8 on windows 7 it throws api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll missing

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, windows-7, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to run the planet scale cli and the docs said to install mysql,

After I installed mysql shell 8 and tried to run it, it throws:

`api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll missing`

where does `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` come from?

and how do I add it?

**Windows 7 64bit, powershell 2.0 , windows .net framework 4**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a mySQL bug report and this is what they said:

```
Thank you for your bug report.

However, this is not our bug.

This is a missing Windows system library. You can read more about that
here:
```

https://wiki-drivers.com/du-101/?m=src_evp_adwords_du_dll_e&build=ppc&content=ppcdudll&build=ppc&kw=api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIl6LTgbjJ-wIVmeFRCh1KvwH_EAAYASAAEgJWwvD_BwE

alternative solution would be to try upgrade to PowerShell 5 and install via scoop or something of that nature

I've yet to try this solution due to my windows 7 laptop's screen messing up causing me to upgrade my laptop.

Thought it would be helpful to follow up with my findings